# What does $ sign at the end of function name indicate?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

Here is the code I'm reviewing...

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
// reducer
import { playerRegister, PlayerState } from './player';
export function getPlayer$ (state$: Observable<MyAppState>): Observable<PlayerState> {
  return state$.select(state => state.player);
};
```

Comment: Some people use it to indicate that the function is asynchronous.

Comment: `$` is just a character with absolutely no significance

Comment: @robby-cornelissen thanks, you can move it to answer.

Comment: Also have a look at [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/205853/1048572)

Comment: Observables and Finnish Notation: https://medium.com/@benlesh/observables-and-finnish-notation-df8356ed1c9b

Comment: Some developers use $ convention for indicating dom element. So in your question it might be used to indicate the function which will modify the dom elements.

Comment: @JaromandaX I think to say "`$` is just a character with no significance" isn't particularly helpful as the OP has obviously seen, or suspects that, there is some convention in place whereby the `$` is used to _indicate_ some quality of the variable. Hence the question "What [does it] indicate?". A similar question could be "What does the `Factory` suffix indicate on a class name?" and an equally unhelpful response would be "The characters `F`, `a`, `c`, `t`, `o`, `r` and `y` have no special significance".

Comment: @ElRonnoco - that's your opinion, and no, the word "Factory" conveys meaning, because it's a word with meaning. The symbol "$" in a variable name or object property does not have any significance in the code posted or anywhere else for that matter

Comment: I have started liking this convention. Mainly because the way you treat a regular array vs observable is so much different. Making it super easy while coding as well as when reviewing a code.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Syntactically, the dollar (`$`) character has no special meaning in [JavaScript identifiers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-names-and-keywords).

It is, however, sometimes used by convention to indicate that a variable holds an [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) or that a function will return an `Observable`.

Comment: Never seen that. Is this convention codified anywhere, does a popular library use it?

Comment: @Bergi I've seen it around a couple of times. As far as I know, not limited to a specific library or framework, but looking into it further.

Comment: I don't want to split hairs, but Observables are not functions, and the logic within them or attached to them is not necessarily executed asynchronously.

Comment: @Bergi A reference to Cycle.js mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671700/angular2-style-guide-property-with-dollar-sign)

Comment: @MattBurnell You're right. I have however seen it being used for observables as well as for promises and other types of async functions. Will update my answer.

Comment: $ suffix can be used for anything as a personal choice, but there's no convention to use it with promises or other async stuff. It's for observables only.

Comment: @estus Can't find any public reference anymore, so limited my answer to Observables.

Comment: @ Matt Burnell: I think he refers to a function that returns an observable. At least that is when I use it. I define a getter that returns an observable and, to indicate that, I add a $ to its name.

Comment: Angular does refer to this in its documentation as a "widely adopted naming convention for observables". However, it does not enforce this in any way, "feel free to use it or not".
https://angular.io/guide/observables#naming-conventions-for-observables

Answer (score 49):

This is a code convention named **Finnish Notation**, apparently due to the origin of the [developer](https://twitter.com/andrestaltz) that is [attributed](https://medium.com/@benlesh/observables-and-finnish-notation-df8356ed1c9b) for first using it. It's used to indicate the `Observable` type of a variable or function.

The idea is that an Observable usually represents a stream of multiple Value**s** and a pluralized variable / function name would indicate this. To not be confused with array variables (which are usually also pluralized), the `$` character is used instead of the `s`. When reading the variable, you'd read the `$` as an `s`.

### Example

When naming an array, you'll most likely use the proper plural form of a single element's name, as in:

`const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'turtle']`

While, if you had an observable that emitted those three values, you'd use:

`const pet$ = from(['cat', 'dog', 'turtle']) // read: pets`

It's up to you and your team whether you want to use it. I guess there is no explicit consensus as of now, so you can have a long and meaningful argument about it ;-). There are already [tslint rules](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/blob/master/docs/index.md) available that allow you to enforce your decision.

Comment: Thank you for not only explaining _how_ it is used, but also _why_, and _what_ it is called. Your thoroughness makes this a much more useful answer, and makes the concept easier to remember!

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure if it's used more widely than within the RxJS community, but within this community it's commonly used to indicate that a variable is a stream (i.e. an Observable) or that a function returns such a stream.

Answer (score 6):

For a function it means it returns an observable.

For a variable it means it is an observable.

This notation is widely used in Angular projects and I find it very useful to quickly see that it is an observable and not the actual value.