# Is it valid to use $ for variable name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if it is valid to use $ in front of variable name in JavaScript (like PHP).

So can I do something like this:

```
var $x = 1; // Is this valid with the $ in front?
var y = 2; // This is valid JavaScript
```

I have tested a little and it seems to work, but want to make sure it is valid and will work across all browsers before I do it.

Comment: Ever seen jQuery?

Comment: If you're writing new code, consider `const`/`let` rather than `var`.  Their scope is much more clear/less quirky.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. This is an example you can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43083577/1550476.

Comment: Sure, check official docs: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-names-and-keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has always been valid since the first edition of the ECMAScript language specification.

According to the 10th edition of the ECMAScript language specification published in 2019 (see: [ECMAScript Language: Lexical Grammar - Names and Keywords](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-names-and-keywords)), the grammar for variable names is:

```
IdentifierName::
  IdentifierStart
  IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart::
  UnicodeIDStart
  $
  _
  \ UnicodeEscapeSequence

IdentifierPart::
  UnicodeIDContinue
  $
  \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
  <ZWNJ>
  <ZWJ>

...
```

As you can see, it is valid to have `$` anywhere in the variable name.

This has always been the case since the first edition of ECMAScript standard published in 1997. Section 4.5 *Identifiers* from the first edition says:

> An identifier is a character sequence  of unlimited length, where each character in the sequence must be a letter, a decimal digit, an underscore (_) character, or a dollar sign ($) character, and the first character may not be a decimal digit.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript variable names can begin with a letter, $ or _ . As long as you dont start your variable name with a number, your good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Valid, yes, but a code style not usually used unless it has meaning.

I've seen some folks use `$someVar` to indicate a jQuery-decorated element, for example.  (Because, jQuery by default uses `$` for its name.)

I would not recommend using it unless you have a specific reason, and are consistent in your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Javascript accepts $ and _ as variable names. It works and it is valid in any browser.[Check it here](https://javascript.info/variables)