# Angular2/4 : Refresh Data Realtime

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, setinterval, angular2-observables, subscriptions

I need to refresh the data in a component page in an interval. Also I need to refresh the data after doing some action. I am using Obeservables in the service so that I can subscribe to when the response is ready. I am pushing the subscriptions to a object so that I can clear that on `ngDestroy`, I think, I have the following methods to achieve the same.

**Method 1 : setInterval**

I have set an interval on `ngOnInit`, which will call the refreshData in equal interval. The interval object will be cleared using `clearInterval` in `ngOnDestroy` method.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    data: any;
    interval: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.refreshData();
        this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
            this.refreshData(); 
        }, 5000);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    refreshData(){
        this.subscription.add(
            this.myService.getData()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.data = data;
                })
        );
    }

    doAction(){
        this.subscription.add(
            this.myService.doAction()
                .subscribe(result => {
                    if(result === true){
                        this.refreshData();
                    }
                })
        );
    }
}
```

Q1 : On each refresh call a subscription will be added to the `subscription` object, will that increase the memory usage and may crash the browser if user keeps the page opened for a while?

**Method2 : Observable.timer**

This method is using a timer which will created after the data is refreshed.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    data: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.refreshData();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    refreshData(){
        this.subscription.add(
            this.myService.getData()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.data = data;
                    this.subscribeToData();
                })
        );
    }

    subscribeToData(){
        this.subscription.add(
            Observable.timer(10000).subscribe(() => this.refreshData())
        );
    }

    doAction(){
        this.subscription.add(
            this.myService.doAction()
                .subscribe(result => {
                    if(result === true){
                        this.refreshData();
                    }
                })
        );
    }
}
```

Q2 : I have the same question(Q1) here. This way, will add the timers also to the subscription object, so infact the subscriptions in the subscription object is doubled.

Q3 : To refresh data after the action method - doAction(), the refreshData is called. So will that create another chain of timer?

Q4 : Which is the better way without memory leaks or if there exists any other way?

Answer (score 37):

You should be able to do this without problems:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshData();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
        this.refreshData(); 
    }, 5000);
}

refreshData(){
    this.myService.getData()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
        })
    );
}
```

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-angular-2-http-calls-to-prevent-memory-leak) Angular will take care of cleaning up after itself.

**However**, if you're going to have a live data stream in your app I'd suggest changing your component so that rather than subscribing to each response of your service's http request, you instead subscribe once to a new observable `data$` property of your service in your component's `ngOnInit()`. Then, on interval (as you're doing) call `updateData()` on your service (or setup the interval *inside* your service) but don't subscribe. When your service successfully fetches the data, it pushes the next value to its observable `data$` property, giving you a stream of data from your service that you can react to anywhere in your app.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.data$.subscribe(data => { // subscribe once to the data stream
        this.data = data;
    })

    this.refreshData();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
        this.refreshData(); 
    }, 5000);
}

refreshData(){
    this.myService.updateData(); // simply signal for the service to update its data stream
}
```

With `myService.data$` being an observable BehaviourSubject updated in your service, something like this:

```
public data$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});

updateData() {
    let data = this.http.get('http://www.data.com').map((data)=>{
        return data.json();
    }).do((data)=>{
        this.data$.next(data);
    })
}
```

That way you can avoid multiple subscriptions and make the data stream available to any component that needs it.

Comment: Can you please explain `this.myService.data$`?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any significance in `$` at the end of the property?

Comment: Just a convention to signify an observable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671700/angular2-style-guide-property-with-dollar-sign.

Comment: I tried and it won't worked because to send the request, there needs to be a subscribe. Only adding `this.myService.updateData()` didn't worked.

Comment: @SpaceFozzy here you describe **interval** what is type of?

Comment: Don't forget to `clearInterval()` in `ngOnDestroy()`

Answer (score 8):

I am just extending @SpaceFozzy's answer a little bit so that it will be helpful for future visitors here. For refreshing the data, I have used the way of @SpaceFozzy. But for subscriptions, I got a better approach. Please have a look at the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163. So I have updated my service and component as follows. Hope this helps.

My Component

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private unsubscribe: Subject = new Subject();

    data: any;
    interval: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.refreshData();
        if(this.interval){
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.refreshData();
        }, 10000);


        this.myService.data$.takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
            });

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unsubscribe.next();
        this.unsubscribe.complete();
    }

    refreshData(){
        this.myService.updateData()
            .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
            .subscribe();
    }

    doAction(){
        this.subscription.add(
            this.myService.doAction()
                .subscribe(result => {
                    if(result === true){
                        this.refreshData();
                    }
                })
        );
    }
}
```

My Service

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private dataSubject: BehaviorSubject<YourDataModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    data$: Observable<YourDataModel[]> = this.dataSubject.asObservable();

    updateData(): Observable<any>  {
        return this.getData().do((data) => {
            this.dataSubject.next(data);
        });
    }

    // My data is an array of model objects
    getData(): Observable<YourDataModel[]>{
        return this.http.get('/path')
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let data = response.json() && response.json().your_data_objects;
                if(data){
                    return data;
                }
            })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please don't forget to clearInterval on ngDestroy.

```
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unsubscribe.next();
        this.unsubscribe.complete();
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
```

Comment: @JohnPeters Read more https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks