# refreshing data on page every X seconds for angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application

I need to refresh data of angular component each 30 seconds. I use simple `setInterval`:

```
 this.interval = setInterval(() => {
               this.refresh(); // api call
            }, 10000);
```

However, this is incorrect, because even when I navigate to another "page" (in angular SPA everything is one page, so it is not really another page), refresh is happening each 30 seconds.

What is the correct way to refresh data every 30 seconds only when on specific page/component?

Comment: This article will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947551/angular2-4-refresh-data-realtime

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could destroy interval on `OnDestroy` life cycle hook of the component.

Using `clearInterval(this.interval)`

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   if (this.interval) {
     clearInterval(this.interval);
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems similer answer of mine

Comment: I know, because we wrote on the same time, more less.

Comment: Btw, you could also mention that component should implement OnDestroy... otherwise ondestroy never called, right?

Comment: Yes, for the editor you should implements `OnDestroy` and it's the best approach. For the final result you could avoid it because at runtime Javascript lose interfaces declared with Typescript. But the best practice is to insert it.

Answer (score 1):

You could clearInterval in `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook of component

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

> `ngOnDestroy` will call every time component destroy in digest cycle and it will clear your interval as well (If you do so).
>   Generally used to call logic which we don't require after navigation of current route to another.

Answer (score 1):

**try this.**

```
save: boolean = false;
autoSave() {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log('setTimeOut');
            this.save = true;

        }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
routerOnActivate() {
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
               this.refresh(); // api call
            }, 10000);
}

routerOnDeactivate() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to another page, you have to clear the interval you are setting.

```
this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
  ...
});

navigateToAnotherPage = () => {
  //function to navigate to another page
  clearInterval(this.interval);
  router.navigate(...)//if you are using router to navigate
}
```

Comment: What is `navigateToAnotherPage` here? when this is being called?

Comment: Whatever the questioner is using to navigate to another page. Perhaps a function call that navigates using `router.navigate`. Not sure how the navigation is happening as it is not mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @PardeepJain but yeah I agree with your solution. `ngOnDestroy` seems like a more generic fix.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not Angular specific so asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage reactive style.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
/*
  timer takes a second argument, how often to emit subsequent values
  in this case we will emit first value after 1 second and subsequent
  values every 2 seconds after
*/
const source = timer(0, 2000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5......
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Reference - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer