# How to write a Angular 6 Subscriber function

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, subscriber

I have seen a code in a video and it is as follows.

```
this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe( next:event=> this.onDragEnd(event));
```

When in include it in my directive folder it gives an error as follows.

```
ERROR in src/app/draggable/dropzone.directive.ts(16,49): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

How can i implement in Angular 6?

Comment: `(next: Event) => ...` where next is the variable **name** and Event is the variable **type** (which shouldn't be necessary: you can just write `next => ...`.

Comment: For an irrelevant or no present variable jsut use () => .....
Wrapping your body in { ..... } is a good practice:  
() => { } For further syntax understanding look up lamda or arrow function

Comment: this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe(event => this.onDragEnd(event)); worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a type in this way :

```
this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe( (next:event) => {
  this.onDragEnd(next);
});
```

Or, if event is of type next :

```
this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe( (event:next) => {
  this.onDragEnd(event);
});
```

**Note:** The `$` should be putted at the **start** of `Observable`, `subject` and `BehaviorSubject`, not at the end.

Comment: Err, no. The convention is to put the $ at the end. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671700/angular2-style-guide-property-with-dollar-sign

Answer (score 0):

```
this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe( next:event=> this.onDragEnd(event));
```

This is right way of defining a subscriber function in `angular6`.

But the problem is in the syntax of arrow function which you passed in subscribe call.

to define an arrow function syntax is

```
(arguments)=>{
     ......  
     code 
     ..... 
 }
```

like if you have only one line of code in method body you can define the arrow function like this

```
(argument)=> console.log('for single line in the method block');
```

but in case of when you have single line of code but more then 2 arguments or need to define the type of the argument(like you do in your case **next:event** ) you need to follow the first one syntax .

so same problem you are facing in your case

`this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe( next:event=> this.onDragEnd(event));`

when you pass the argument next:Event (next argument of Event type) it through an error while you are building this .

**if  you have intelliSense in your editor it gives you a warning that exepected 1 got 2 something like that.**

so below define both syntax should work .

- > this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe( (next:event)=> {this.onDragEnd(event)});
- > this.droppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe( next=>this.onDragEnd(event));