# ngFor for delayed data

Tags: angular

I have a component that takes the URL param, call API and displays the data. Most basic and typically sample:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => { 
      const id = params.id;     
      this.loadAssets(id);
    });
  }

  loadAssets(id)
  {   
    this.apiService.getAssetGroup(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.assetGroup  =  data;   
      this.assetSubGroupList = data.assetSubGroupList;
      console.log(this.assetGroup);
    });
  }
```

In my html i do a simple loop:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <div *ngFor="let subGroup of assetGroup.assetSubGroupList">
            <div>SubGroup: {{subGroup.name}}</div>
            <div *ngFor="let asset of subGroup.assetList">Asset: {{asset.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess this is some of to most common scenarios in web development. However, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'assetSubGroupList' of undefined at Object.eval
>   [as updateDirectives] (AssetsComponent.html:5)

My best guess is this is because when the page is loaded assetGroup is null. The page actually ends working after the data is loaded, but i dont want the first error. I am thinking there must be some standard way of handling this scenario in Angular. Do you always initialize variables, use ngIf or even something smarter?

Comment: *assetGroup is null*: no. As the error message says, it's undefined. ngIf is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `async` pipe instead. That way you won't have to take care of `unsubcribe`ing as well which is generally recommended and done to avoid any memory leaks.

Just declare a property in your TS Class named `assetGroup$`(we ideally suffix a `$` sign for a value that might be of type Observable. It's just a code convention that you can read more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37928549/2622292).) and then assign it in the `loadAssets` function like this:

```
assetGroup$;
...
loadAssets(id) {
  this.assetGroup$ = this.apiService.getAssetGroup(id);
}
```

Then in your template code use it like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <div *ngFor="let subGroup of (assetGroup$ | async).assetSubGroupList">
      <div>SubGroup: {{subGroup.name}}</div>
      <div *ngFor="let asset of subGroup.assetList">Asset: {{asset.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks looks much more clean. How do you declare assetGroup$ ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. `assetGroup$;` is just a property on your TS Class.

Comment: I really like this method. But it moves the problem to the sub properties. I know get: property 'name' of undefined. Also I needed to define it as following:  private  assetGroup$:  Observable<AssetGroup>;. Do you have a smart way for handling the properties too?

Comment: First up, it shouldn't be a private property as that is something that you're going to use in your template. So it should be public. Second thing, since the template part is going to run only after it has unwrapped the value, you shouldn't be getting the error that you just mentioned. You can have a look at a [**Sample StackBlitz here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-generic-http-get?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I'm declaring a `users$` property on my class and using it in my template using `async`

Comment: Your right I had a <H1>{{assetGroup.name}} another place in the html. Thanks highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `?` operator to `assetGroup`

```
<div *ngFor="let subGroup of assetGroup?.assetSubGroupList">
            <div>SubGroup: {{subGroup.name}}</div>
            <div *ngFor="let asset of subGroup.assetList">Asset: {{asset.name}}</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It got me further. Now same error for the name property. Cant you add ? to that too?  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <div *ngFor="let subGroup of assetGroup?.assetSubGroupList">
            <div>SubGroup: {{subGroup?.name}}</div>
            <div *ngFor="let asset of subGroup?.assetList">Asset: {{asset?.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @ThomasSegato yes

Answer (score 1):

It is the reason indeed, one way, you can just use this line     `this.assetSubGroupList = data.assetSubGroupList;` to iterate through, so `<div *ngFor="let subGroup of assetSubGroupList">`

Or you can do a check using the `?` operator like so

```
<div *ngFor="let subGroup of assetGroup?.assetSubGroupList">
```