# Updating object property inside an array of objects

Tags: angular

I'm trying to update a property in an object inside an array using an EventEmitter in a child component.

```js
interface productItem {
  keepOpen: boolean;
}

products$:productItem[] = Array(7).fill(
    {
      keepOpen:false
    }
  )
```

I'm using this function when the user clicks on the button :

```js
shouldKeepAddToBagOpen(dataFromChild: boolean, index: number): void {
    // handle callback
    this.keepAddToBagOpen = dataFromChild;
    this.products$[index].keepOpen = dataFromChild;
 
  }
```

However it is affecting all the items in the array, not only the one with the given `index`:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: The variable with [postfix `$` are for Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37671700/8017690).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Array.fill gets passed an object, it will copy the reference and fill the array with references to that object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#using_fill

You could instead use something like:

```
 products = Array.from({length:7},()=> ({'keepOpen':false}))
```